# Multiple if else inside if else statements - Simulate a scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, mousewheel

The question has been asked a lot of times but can't figure why isn't going well.
I'm trying to simulate a scroll to have more flexibilities but need to had many conditions. I get a mousewheel event when going up or down to fadeIn and fadeOut `div`. It is working with one `div` but can't make it with more.

I'm making a demo on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Leshautsdurant/sf9r2ocb/)

```
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {

  if ($('.ecampus').css('opacity') == '1') {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
            // TOP PAGE
    } else {
      $('.pegasebuzz').fadeOut();
      $('.notrecoin').fadeIn();
    }
  }

  else if ($('.pegasebuzz').css('opacity') == '1') {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      $('.pegasebuzz').fadeOut();
      $('.ecampus').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('.pegasebuzz').fadeOut();
      $('.notrecoin').fadeIn();
    }
  }

  else ($('.notrecoin').css('opacity') == '1') {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      $('.notrecoin').fadeOut();
      $('.pegasebuzz').fadeIn();
    } else {
      // BOTTOM PAGE
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: check [this](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: @Durga I used a similar library (Scrollify.js) but I need to do it without a real scroller because it didn't work fine in my case. I'm looking for a fixed transition with the mouse-wheel. Like this website (except the first page) : www.studio-dot.fr

Comment: @Leshautsdurant Check my answer below and mark if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
var scroll=0;
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
if(scroll<10) scroll++;
else{
  scroll=0;
  if ($('.ecampus').css('display') == 'block') {
  
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta  < 0 ) {
   
      $('.ecampus').fadeOut();
      $('.pegasebuzz').fadeIn();
    } else {
      // TOP PAGE
    }
    return;
  }

  if ($('.pegasebuzz').css('display') == 'block') {
   if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta  < 0) {
    $('.pegasebuzz').fadeOut();
     $('.notrecoin').fadeIn();
    } else {
    $('.pegasebuzz').fadeOut();
     $('.ecampus').fadeIn();
   }
   return;
  }

  if ($('.notrecoin').css('display') == 'block') {
   if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
     // BOTTOM PAGE
  } else {
     
     $('.notrecoin').fadeOut();
     $('.pegasebuzz').fadeIn();
   }
   return;
 }
 
 }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.ecampus {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.pegasebuzz {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.notrecoin {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ecampus">
  E-CAMPUS
</div>
<div class="pegasebuzz">
  PEGASEBUZZ
</div>
<div class="notrecoin">
  NOTRE COIN
</div>
```

On every mousewheel event it changes the div. you can check how much scroll value you want to add according to your div.

Comment: Thank you very much Durga ! By any chance, do you know if I can add a delay to prevent multiple transitions ?

Comment: @Leshautsdurant check updated snippet added variable to give some delay.

Comment: This is awesome ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
  if ($('.ecampus').css('display') == 'block') {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      // TOP PAGE
    } else {
      $('.ecampus').fadeOut();
      $('.pegasebuzz').fadeIn();
      $('.notrecoin').fadeOut();
    }
  } else if ($('.pegasebuzz').css('display') == 'block') {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      $('.pegasebuzz').fadeOut();
      $('.ecampus').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('.notrecoin').fadeOut();
      $('.pegasebuzz').fadeOut();
      $('.notrecoin').fadeIn();
    }
  } else if ($('.notrecoin').css('display') == 'block') {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      $('.ecampus').fadeOut();
      $('.notrecoin').fadeOut();
      $('.pegasebuzz').fadeIn();
    } else {}
  } else {}

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.ecampus {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.pegasebuzz {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.notrecoin {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ecampus">
  E-CAMPUS
</div>
<div class="pegasebuzz">
  PEGASEBUZZ
</div>
<div class="notrecoin">
  NOTRE COIN
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Yogen for your answer !